# stored an image as a blob in MYSQL but now im having trouble displaying it in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Ello, so Ive inserted the jpeg via PHP into mySQL database and the image is showing as having been stored so I'm pretty sure its not a insertion issue, but I'm not sure how I retrieve it or decode it now as its just showing up as a '[?]' box on the frontend.

I'm sure it has to do with the way im pulling it, but the articles I've looked up are showing it done this way, however I'm pulling it a little bit differently I guess as I'm binding it to a parameter instead of pulling it via array ($row['column_name']) ?

Any help would be appreciated on understanding this. Also I've seen it done a lot more with storing the file in a directory, but storing the path in the database, is this a more efficient method? If I'm deleting a post I want the image associated with it to be gone as well so I figured this was a more efficient method?

**insert**

```
$imgname = $_FILES['file_']['name'];
$file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['file_']['tmp_name']));
$imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['file_']['tmp_name']);

$newtop = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO topics (topic_section, topic_subject, topic_img, topic_nameop, topic_comment, topic_imgname)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$section = 14;
$newtop->bind_param("ssssss", $section, $subject, $file, $user, $comment, $imgname);
$newtop->execute();
$topicid = $newtop->insert_id;

$postinit = 1;
$logpost = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post_img, post_comment, topic_id, post_nameop, post_init, post_section, post_imgname)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$logpost->bind_param("sssssss", $file, $comment, $topicid, $user, $postinit, $section, $imgname);
$logpost->execute();
```

**Retrieval**

```
$tquery = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM topics");
$tquery->execute();
$tquery->store_result();

if($tquery->num_rows){
    $tquery->bind_result($tid, $tsection, $tsubject, $timg, 
                        $tdate, $tname, $tcomment, $timgname);

    while($tquery->fetch()){
        echo "<div style='float:left'>
                <h1>".$tsubject."</h1><br>
                <img src='data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,".base64_encode($timg)."'>
            </div>";

    }
    echo "<div style='clear:both'></div>";
}
```

Comment: *"Also I've seen it done a lot more with storing the file in a directory, but storing the path in the database, is this a more efficient method?"* I would say yes, it's a lot better. Why? Because it requires less steps and divides the task of database and web server. Let the web server handle files, it's what it does best afterall. Let the database be about data.

Comment: Alternatively, make sure your database is set to utf8_general_ci and that you have the charset set as utf-8 in your website header as well. Other than that I would most definitely advice you to let the web server handle files. Also, it's important to note that Blob images won't be cached as normal images in a directory would, which also hurts performance.

Comment: If you base64-decode the base64-encoded image data in the img tag produced by your php script, is it the same as that of the original image?

Comment: Using `addslashes()` on the file has every possibility of corrupting the file. Maybe this is what you have done

Comment: I suggest you base64_encode() the file before storing it to the database.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thats what it was! I removed the addslashes() and used base64_encode before inserting and then on the retrieval simply 
``<img src='data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,".$timg."'> ``
and it worked like a charm!

Comment: @Martin thank you! I'll probably change it to this method then.

Comment: @Martin " Also, it's important to note that Blob images won't be cached as normal images in a directory would, which also hurts performance." Ohhh I see, yeah good point.